# Not able to read PNG format Image using Jmagick library

Tags: png, jmagick

I am able to read JPEG format image and can write JPEG format image. I want to do same for PNG format image but i am not getting how to do that.

Comment: Any specific problem you are having? What did you try?

Comment: ImageInfo textImage = new ImageInfo("storage/sdcard0/aaawatermark/image.png");
MagickImage cvTextImage = new MagickImage(textImage);

Comment: I'm not able to read png image. and also not able to write it.

Comment: perhaps libpng is missing?

Comment: @Zac Kindly tell me where to add lib png? If i'm not wrong it is png library?

Comment: @Farrakh it depends on your linux package manager: check  http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-tutorials-howtos-reference-material/64958-how-install-software-linux.html for further help

Comment: @Zac got no help, Above mentioned code is able to read JPEG file but than why not for PNG file?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same concept as jpeg. One of the "magicks" of the library is that it is largely type independent when writing the code. Try doing it the same way.

If you're attempting to do conversion, maybe try looking [here](http://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2012/12/convert-png-to-jpeg-using-jmagick-java.html).

Comment: String fileName = "storage/sdcard0/aaawatermark/canvas.jpg";
                  ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(fileName);
                  MagickImage mainImage = new MagickImage(info);
               
                  String outFileName = "storage/sdcard0/aaawatermark/canvasaaa.png";
                  mainImage.setImageFormat("png");
                  mainImage.setFileName(outFileName);
                  mainImage.writeImage(info);

Comment: I am doing this to write in png format,but i'm getting nothing. I also tried your given link if i am able to convert it but getting nothing.

Comment: ImageInfo textImage = new ImageInfo("storage/sdcard0/aaawatermark/image.png"); MagickImage cvTextImage = new MagickImage(textImage);

Comment: I'm not able to read png image. and also not able to write it.